# React with Brackets

Tags: html, reactjs

I have decided to learn React today. I use normally Brackets.So first I have added sources into my html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/jsx" src="index.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have a div called root there I would like to pass a H2 text with React.This is my index.js file

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Aloo</h1> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

It gives me no error and also no text on the page. Also I dont know why <\h1> is yellow on brackets but before that it is white.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In this case of syntax highlighting, you can set your language preference to "JSX" from the bottom menu in your Brackets IDE (by default it is set to "Javascript" when you are working on ".js" file), you can also set other language if you work on them.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bff8q.png)

Answer (score 1):

As shown [in the getting started guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#online-playgrounds) you need Babel to transpile JSX into JS in the browser.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<!-- Don't use this in production: -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and should mark your JSX as `text/babel` not `text/jsx`.

> Also I dont know why <\h1> is yellow on brackets

You've given your JSX file a `.js` extension so your text editor is applying JavaScript syntax highlighting to it. Since it isn't JavaScript, it gets it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired download some different plugin for proper React syntax highlighting? Usually when you try to use some frameworks, default editor syntax highlighting is not enough and you need additional extensions. Also you can choose syntax highlighting for proper language/tool/frameworks in settings of your IDE. I don't exacly knew where to find that in Brackets but in VS Code it's [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWRK8.png).

[Here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Language-Support) is also how to define and set different language in Brackets.

And for some reasons you may also need a different theme, which support react. [Here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/extend.brackets/dark-revolution/dark-revolution-1.9.1.zip) is one that I've found.

Comment: Thanks ,I have changed syntax highlighting to JSX now it seems better however I still dont get the text in div called Root. I have not download any React files, I thought just with these two script It would work.Should not be ?

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

Comment: No, syntax highlighting don't depends on libraries, what you've added to your code. Editor scans your code and then choose automatically syntax highlighting. Sometimes it isn't working well, so you must choose it manually in settings. And as I said earlier, often you must have theme that support language/framework, and extensions. You can easy install it in Brackets clicking in extension tab and searching for it. Your div isn't well displayed, probably because your theme don't support react.